# How to remove unwanted code left by an uninstalled and deleted plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm currently searching a piece of code that I want to be removed. That code was left by a plugin named [page-loading-effects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-loading-effects/).

My website is https://reggaedivecenter.com and when I visit the homepage, I can see these in my console:

[image]

And when I click on that, I saw these one:

[image]

I spent hours finding that piece of code that I want to be removed on some of the themes PHP files. Is there anything I can do with it?

Comment: Uninstalled, or _deleted_?

Comment: Also - pro tip: use an IDE such as PHPStorm, and it'll take you _seconds_ to find this code, rather than _hours_.  Lastly - that sure looks like either the plugin is not deleted, or else that plugin modified your theme's header.php file....

Comment: @cale_b thanks, I updated my post.

Comment: @cale_b I uninstalled and deleted it, but that piece of code is left.

Comment: Depending on your webhost, they may have cached your homepage which is why stray code is being leftover.

Comment: @1000Nettles Yes I think so too. I'm using WP cache and deleted the cache but nothing happens. I am now downloading the files via ftp and try to search the files for that code.